# what technique we need to integrate this integral?

Tags: integration

$\int_{2}^{4}\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^2}\mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y$

I can't see it could be sovled by substitution or by parts

Comment: Are you sure substitution won't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_2^4 \int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx\,dy&=2\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,d(x^2)\\\\
&=\left.\left(-\frac23(1-x^2)^{3/2}\right)\right|_0^1\\\\
&=\frac23
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, shouldn't it be $1/2$ rather than 2 on the righ hand side?

Comment: @whoisit You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Are you asking about the final answer?  If so, it is indeed $\frac23$.  -Mark